# How to delete an event from fullcalendar on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm in the middle of developing a drag and drop event fullcalendar with a resource column. I'm able to drag and drop events on the calendar and save it to the database. For the resource column, I have an add room button that allows users to add the room which also gets saved in the database. The resources and events are successfully being fetched and displayed on the calendar. 
Now, I'm working on developing the delete functionality for the same. For now, I'm stuck at deleting the events using a double click.

Here's the code:

main.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var containerEl = document.getElementById("external-events");
var checkbox = document.getElementById("drop-remove");
new FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable(containerEl, {
 itemSelector: ".fc-event",
  eventData: function(eventEl) {
    return {
      title: eventEl.innerText
   };
 }
 });

 var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 schedulerLicenseKey: "GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source",
 plugins: ["interaction", "resourceTimeline", 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
header: {
  left: "promptResource today prev,next",
  center: "title",
  right: 'dayGridMonth,resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
 },
customButtons: {
  promptResource: {
    text: "+ room",
    click: function() {
      var title = prompt("Room name");
      console.log(title);
      if (title) {
        fetch("add_resources.php", {
            method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'text/html' 
             },
             body: encodeFormData({"title": title}),
              }) 
                .then(response => response.text())
             .then(response => { 
            calendar.addResource({
          id: response,
          title: title
        });

        })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    }
  }
},
editable: true,
aspectRatio: 1.5,
defaultView: "resourceTimelineDay",
resourceLabelText: "Rooms",
resources: "all_resources.php",
droppable: true,
drop: function(info) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
  }
},
eventLimit: true,
events: "all_events.php",
displayEventTime: false,
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

  if (event.allDay === "true") {
    event.allDay = true;
  } else {
    event.allDay = false;
  }
},


selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
eventClick: function (info) {    
        var confimit = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
        if (confimit) {             
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_event.php",
                  data: "&id=" + info.event.id,
                success: function (response) {

                    if(parseInt(response) > 0) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', info.event.id);
                        displayMessage("Deleted Successfully");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },
eventReceive: function(info) {
  console.log(calendar.getResources());
  console.log(info.event);
  var eventData = {
    title: info.event.title,
    start: moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
    end: moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
    resourceid: info.event._def.resourceIds[0]
  };

  console.log(eventData);
  //send the data via an AJAX POST request, and log any response which comes from the server
  fetch("add_event.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
    body: encodeFormData(eventData)
  })

    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));    
}        
});
calendar.render();
 });

 const encodeFormData = data => {
     var form_data = new FormData();
   for (var key in data) {
     form_data.append(key, data[key]);
   }
  return form_data;
 };
```

delete_event.php

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$sql = "DELETE FROM Events WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
 if ($stmt->execute()) {
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
    return null;
   }
 ?>
```

When I'm trying to delete an event using the above code, I double click on the event, I see the message asking if I really want to delete the event, but it doesn't really get deleted. I don't see the delete_event.php being called in the network panel. The console has the error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I'm not sure what is wrong in the code above.

Comment: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" means you didn't include jQuery in your page, but tried to use some jQuery code. You seem to have tried to use `$.ajax({` instead of `fetch` for some reason, even though in your previous questions we have discussed the fact that you aren't using jQuery any more, and therefore cannot use jQuery functions. I also showed you how to use `fetch`.

Comment: P.S. `eventClick` responds to a single-click on the event, not double-click.

Comment: I didn't just copy paste someone else's code. But yes, I had built in fullcalendar version 3 earlier, and used the same code. I should have looked the documentation before.

Comment: Okay. But I can use the eventClick function right? In that case, I would be unsure on how to define the id in there?

Comment: Tried something like this. It's incomplete though. Can you please check?
eventClick: function (info) {
        
            var confimit = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
            if (confimit) {
                fetch("delete_event.php", {
                  method: "POST",
               headers: {
               Accept: "application/json"
            }
      
      });
    
            
            }
        },
The above code loads the delete_events.php file in the network panel. But gives an error "id undefined". Clearly, it's not being defined there.

Comment: That's better. But yes you need to send the ID to the server. You can do it quite easily. Just add a body to the request, the same way you do in your existing request to `add_resources.php`. The pattern is the same, only the actual data and parameter name needs to change. e.g. `body: encodeFormData({"id": info.event.id})` I expect should be correct.

Comment: Hey, added the line of code in the function. ` eventClick: function (info) { var confimit = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");if (confimit) {fetch("delete_event.php", {method: "POST",headers: {Accept: "application/json"},body: encodeFormData({"id": info.event.id})  });  }}` . Now I'm getting an error  "The active result for the query contains no fields. in C:\wamp64\www\Form\delete_event.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\Form\delete_event.php(15):"

Comment: This is after I click on the event, confirm, then the delete_event.php file gets called in the network panel and I see this in the response tab

Comment: That'll be because of `return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. It makes no sense. 1) you can't `return` because you _aren't inside a function_. We have discussed this before, more than once. I suggest you look up the correct usages of the `return` keyword in PHP. 2) A SQL `DELETE` command doesn't return any results, so you can't `fetch` anything from it. (P.S. Point 2 is the source of your error. Point 1 is just an aside about logic and the correct use of the keyword.)

Comment: Correct. I changed it the last few lines of the sql code. Can yo please check the below code: if ($stmt->execute()) {$conn->commit(); return true;} else {$conn->rollback();return false;}. With this code, the event gets deleted but I still have an error in the response tab, which is - There is no active transaction in C:\wamp64\www\Form\delete_event.php:15

Comment: Yes. Compare that to your add_resources.php code. You haven't started a transaction. So, when you come to commit the transaction (the `$conn->commit()` line), it cannot find any open transactions, in order to commit it. You need `$conn->beginTransaction();` just before the `$sql = ...` line. Always compare your code to another working version of the same process! P.S. Do you know what a transaction is?

Comment: And `return false;` and `return true;` in there are **still wrong**. You **cannot** "return" from outside a function. It won't cause an outright crash, but it also won't do anything useful, or send any values. From the main block of script (which that code is in) you don't need to return - the script will end automatically when the last command has been executed. If you want to send `true` or `false` back to the browser, that needs to be made part of the output of the script - i.e. you should write `echo true;` and `echo false;` instead of `return true;` and `return false;` respectively.

Comment: Please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php for more info.

Comment: No. I'm not sure what a transaction means. 
I'll go through the manual too. Appreciate the help. Please post an answer to the question as it might help other stackoverflow users. Also, can you recommend some basic projects for me that can help learn php and js?

Comment: Maybe read this (and anything else you can find by googling "SQL transaction"): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm to start to understand. In your case you don't really need a transaction particularly, because you're only executing one command. Transactions are useful for ensuring the integrity of multiple actions (so that if one fails, they all fail, and it doesn't leave the data in a disorderly state which would be hard to recover from).

Comment: In terms of basic projects, I can't recommend anything specific from my own knowledge. Googling "php basic tutorials" returns a lot of results for courses, tutorials etc. I'm sure the same is true for JavaScript.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few modifications to your code.

1) use fetch() instead of $.ajax, then you won't get any error messages about jQuery being missing. Ensure you put the event ID into the body of the request.

2) use the fullCalendar v4 syntax for `eventClick`, instead of v3 - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick.

3) Remove the `$stmt->fetch` command from your PHP - a SQL `DELETE` operation doesn't return any results, so there is nothing to fetch. I also removed the meaningless `return` statements, because you're not inside a function, and your script doesn't have any further code which needs to be prevented from executing.

eventClick:

```
eventClick: function (info) { 
  var confimit = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
  if (confimit) {
    fetch("delete_event.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: encodeFormData({"id": info.event.id}) }); 
    }
  }
}
```

delete_event.php:

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$sql = "DELETE FROM Events WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo true;
    } else {
    echo false;
   }
 ?>
```